# Are Kubernetes liveness probe failures voluntary or involuntary disruptions?

Tags: kubernetes, livenessprobe

I have an application deployed to Kubernetes that depends on an outside application. Sometimes the connection between these 2 goes to an invalid state, and that can only be fixed by restarting my application.

To do automatic restarts, I have configured a liveness probe that will verify the connection.

This has been working great, however, I'm afraid that if that outside application goes down (such that the connection error isn't just due to an invalid pod state), all of my pods will immediately restart, and my application will become completely unavailable. I want it to remain running so that functionality not depending on the bad service can continue.

I'm wondering if a pod disruption budget would prevent this scenario, as it limits the # of pods down due to a "voluntary" disruption. However, the K8s docs don't state whether liveness probe failure are a voluntary disruption. Are they?

Comment: Is it feasible to migrate the outside application to your Kubernetes cluster? This won't directly answer your question but I'd reckon you could take a look on following articles: [1](https://blog.risingstack.com/designing-microservices-architecture-for-failure/), [2](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-readiness-probes-examples-common-pitfalls/#external-dependencies), [3](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/scalable-and-resilient-apps#resilience_designing_to_withstand_failures)

Comment: @DawidKruk the outside application unfortunately is Azure CosmosDB, which doesn't have the best client drivers for the environment I'm in. However, I've had similar issues using ioredis to connect to my self-hosted Redis cluster, so I'll take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, accordingly to the documentation:

> #### Voluntary and involuntary disruptions
>
> Pods do not disappear until someone (a person or a controller) destroys them, or there is an unavoidable hardware or system software error.
>
> We call these unavoidable cases  *involuntary disruptions*  to an application. Examples are:
>
> - a hardware failure of the physical machine backing the node
> - cluster administrator deletes VM (instance) by mistake
> - cloud provider or hypervisor failure makes VM disappear
> - a kernel panic
> - the node disappears from the cluster due to cluster network partition
> - eviction of a pod due to the node being  [out-of-resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/).
>
> Except for the out-of-resources condition, all these conditions should be familiar to most users; they are not specific to Kubernetes.
>
> We call other cases *voluntary disruptions*. These include both actions initiated by the application owner and those initiated by a Cluster Administrator. Typical application owner actions include:
>
> - deleting the deployment or other controller that manages the pod
> - updating a deployment's pod template causing a restart
> - directly deleting a pod (e.g. by accident)
>
> Cluster administrator actions include:
>
> - [Draining a node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/)  for repair or upgrade.
> - Draining a node from a cluster to scale the cluster down (learn about  [Cluster Autoscaling](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/#readme)  ).
> - Removing a pod from a node to permit something else to fit on that node.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Disruptions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/)*

**So your example is quite different and according to my knowledge it's neither voluntary or involuntary disruption.**

---

Also taking a look on another Kubernetes documentation:

> #### Pod lifetime
>
> Like individual application containers, Pods are considered to be relatively ephemeral (rather than durable) entities. Pods are created, assigned a unique ID ([UID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#uids)), and scheduled to nodes where they remain until termination (according to restart policy) or deletion. If a [Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/) dies, the Pods scheduled to that node are [scheduled for deletion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection) after a timeout period.
>
> Pods do not, by themselves, self-heal. If a Pod is scheduled to a [node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/) that then fails, the Pod is deleted; likewise, a Pod won't survive an eviction due to a lack of resources or Node maintenance. Kubernetes uses a higher-level abstraction, called a [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/), that handles the work of managing the relatively disposable Pod instances.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Pod lifecycle: Pod lifetime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime)*

> #### Container probes
>
> The kubelet can optionally perform and react to three kinds of probes on running containers (focusing on a `livenessProbe`):
>
> - `livenessProbe`: Indicates whether the container is running. If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected to its  [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy). If a Container does not provide a liveness probe, the default state is  `Success`.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Pod lifecycle: Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)*
>
> #### When should you use a liveness probe?
>
> If the process in your container is able to crash on its own whenever it encounters an issue or becomes unhealthy, you do not necessarily need a liveness probe; the kubelet will automatically perform the correct action in accordance with the Pod's  `restartPolicy`.
>
> If you'd like your container to be killed and restarted if a probe fails, then specify a liveness probe, and specify a  `restartPolicy`  of Always or OnFailure.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Pod lifecycle: When should you use a startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-startup-probe)*

According to those information it would be better to create custom liveness probe which should consider internal process health checks and external dependency(liveness) health check. In the first scenario your container should stop/terminate your process unlike the the second case with external dependency.

Answering following question:

> I'm wondering if a pod disruption budget would prevent this scenario.

**In this particular scenario PDB will not help.**

---

I'd reckon giving more visibility to the comment, I've made with additional resources on the matter could prove useful to other community members:

- *[Blog.risingstack.com: Designing microservices architecture for failure](https://blog.risingstack.com/designing-microservices-architecture-for-failure/)*
- *[Loft.sh: Blog: Kubernetes readiness probles examples common pitfalls: External depenedencies](https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-readiness-probes-examples-common-pitfalls/#external-dependencies)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Archiecture: Scalable and resilient apps: Resilience designing to withstand failures](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/scalable-and-resilient-apps#resilience_designing_to_withstand_failures)*

Answer (score 1):

Testing with PodDisruptionBudget.
Pod will still restart at the same time.

## example

https://github.com/AlphaWong/PodDisruptionBudgetAndPodProbe

So yes. like @Dawid Kruk u should create a customized script like following

```
# something like this
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    # generate a random number for sleep
    - 'SLEEP_TIME=$(shuf -i 2-40 -n 1);sleep $SLEEP_TIME; curl -L --max-time 5 -f nginx2.default.svc.cluster.local'
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  # think about the gap between each call
  periodSeconds: 30
  # it is required after k8s v1.12
  timeoutSeconds: 90
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if a pod disruption budget would prevent this scenario.

**Yes**, it will prevent.

As you stated, when the `pod` goes down (or node failure) nothing can do pods from becoming unavailable. However, Certain services require that a minimum number of pods always keep running always.

There could be another way (`Stateful resource`) but it’s one of the simplest Kubernetes resources available.

Note: You can also use a percentage instead of an absolute number in the `minAvailable` field. For example, you could state that `60%` of all pods with the `app=run-always` label need to be running at all times.

Comment: OP asked about voluntary disruptions. From their question it looks like they know about PDB already.

Comment: yes, they know but as per his req. This is the minimum effort to achieve. I edited my answer. Let him come back and share his opinion.. ALso, this is something that needs mew research than a straight answer. Agreed?

Comment: "Yes, it will prevent." --- are you sure PDB prevents liveness probes from restarting the pod?

Comment: @Gupta I need to agree with you on your last comment. Could you please edit your answer to support the last comment you've made (with `loose-loose` situation) so that it would be more visible and explain the circumstances more clearly?

Comment: Edit Comments- _I did not mean that. This is something need to handle at the application level. On one side PDB tries to make pod to be ready as per its nature of implementation and on the other hand Liveness Probe will try to restart the pod in order to make it healthy._

Comment: @Gupta do you have any references or tests that prove this? Otherwise, I might have to run my own in the near future

Comment: For reference, I would say to look out Kubernetes in Action book 
 https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action?query=kuber chapter 15